# Adding entry to "send" menu in photos app

Tags: windows-phone-8

I discovered, then when I hit the "send" menu for an image in my Windows Phone 8 photos app, beside mail, SMS etc. also third party apps like Instagram or WhatsApp are listed there. Can you point me to some SDK doc. which gives instructions on how I can add my own app to this menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Photo extensibility for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202966%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [How to integrate with the Music and Videos Hub for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).